# microSD extreme plus xfer speed over usb

Tags: usb, microsd

I want to know the max xfer speed for a SanDisk Extreme Plus microSD XC 1 V30 card in order to figure out if using a 10Gbps USB hub (Gen 2) would be faster than a 5Gbps USB hub (Gen 1).  In other words, if the microSD XC 1 V30 speed is 5Gbps or less, then using a Gen 2 USB connection would buy me nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All SD card readers are using USB 3.0 (3.1 gen 1 / 3.2 gen 1) and even the UHS-II (fastest sd cards) are not bottlenecked by USB. Just gen an SD card reader with UBS 3.0 and it will be enough.